# Wordpress Website URL messing up

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, compiler-errors

I am facing a problem with my site.

When I navigate to any other URL of the website without navigating from my homepage, there are some miscellaneous test appended to the URL.

I don't even know why is it happening. Do guys have any idea how to sort it out?

For better understanding check it out.

[image: 1st one]

[image: 2nd one]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: In function.php ?

Comment: Add it under the closing tag or before in your php

Comment: In which file ?

Comment: index.php or index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply unfortunately its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something with the theme's JS might be causing some sort of conflict with the AddThis social share bar you have.

I would make sure your theme is up to date, and all plugins as the first step if you haven't done so already.

In the console I tried this:

```
    var a = window.location
      , n = a.hash;
        n = n.replace("!loading", "");
        var i = n + "!loading";
        a.hash = i
    jQuery(".vc_row, .mk-main-wrapper-holder, .mk-page-section, #comments").filter("#" + n.substring(1)).length
```

Which replicates the error.

Changing the selector to:

```
    jQuery(".vc_row, .mk-main-wrapper-holder, .mk-page-section, #comments").filter("#" + n.substring(2)).length
```

gives it valid context, but I'm not entirely sure from what you've posted what is supposed to be happening with all the scripts running on the page.

It should at least get you in the right direction in better troubleshooting it though.

I would also suggest you turn on SCRIPT_DEBUG in your wpconfig which might help you locate the issue in clearer context: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#SCRIPT_DEBUG

It looks like the theme may also be a premium theme, so you should probably contact the theme author to aide in resolving the issue if you're not able to pinpoint a solution since they will be the most familiar with the code, and that's one of the benefits of paying for a theme :)